Which chapter of the manga does Season 7th of My Hero Academia anime start in?
I want to spoil myself with what happens after the first episode of season 7th of the anime of My Hero Academia. Which chapter of the manga should I read?
Which chapter of the manga does Season 7th of My Hero Academia anime start in?

This website says

「僕のヒーローアカデミア」第7期は、原作マンガ34巻収録の第329話から物語がスタート。

So you should start from Episode 329 in Volume 34.
